# Assign the result from with ... as statement to self.bar

Tags: python

In a Python class, a method opened a file, but it is another method that actually use the file object. So I write:

```
def first_method(self):
    with open(FILE) as f:
        self.output = f
        self.another_method()

def another_method(self):
    self.output.write(DATA)
```

As you see, the `another_method` is called by `first_method` in the `with ... as` scope, so I'm sure that the `another_method` will done before `first_method` exiting the `with ... as` scope - it works. However, I'm puzzled about this line:

```
self.output = f
```

Is it good practice to use result from `with ... as` statement in another function? Will this lead to unexpected or uncontrollable behavior?

And, `another_method` is not the only place where `f` is used. Actually, `another_method` is a coroutine, many of it will write to `f` asynchronously. So I have to open the file outside `another_method`.

There are many other context managers facing the same problem, like `aiohttp.ClientSession`, `tqdm.tqdm`. Passing them as a parameter will cause too many parameters.

Actually, the problem arises when I write [this](https://github.com/cshuaimin/aget/blob/f65d9a8423b5335f7d0e2fdb62302826f111797c/aget.py#L162).

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

The `with` statement causes the automatic execution of the object's `__exit__` method at the end of the block. It's reasonable to assume that after `__exit__` the object is in an unusable state, even if you still have a reference to it. Saving it as an object attribute would be ill advised.

In your specific example you'd be better off passing the file explicitly as a parameter to `another_method`.

Comment: This. And if `another_method` is the only place where `f` is used then it probably should open the file itself.

Comment: I have considered passing the file as a parameter, but there will be too many parameters.

Comment: @CSM not sure how adding one parameter to a method suddenly turns into "too many". Maybe you could expand on that a bit in your question?

Comment: @MarkRansom There are some other objects, like 'aiohttp.ClientSession', facing the same problem. I have edited the question.

Comment: @CSM why don't you keep the filename in self.output, and then open it with a `with` statement inside any methods that would need to write to the file?

Comment: @Maxim This program is a async downloader, there are tens of coroutines writing to the file. I think holding tens of file objects points to a same file is even worse.

Comment: @CSM then you should probably not close the file, return a reference to open(filename, 'w') and close it only at the end of your processing